# How can I add multiple input in a list or array with repeating element for n times?

Tags: java, arrays

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(a, 1);
        System.out.println(list);
```

Though my output should be : {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}
Like that and I am only able to add one number.
Please help.

Comment: `nCopies` will make `a` copies of the integer one. Why do you expect it to product that list?

Comment: I thought to put nCopies various times in the same line and it will work but it gave error... @Michael

Comment: is your output is correct? or it should be `{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}`? @Remus

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
        int duplicateByNumber = 4;
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        List<Integer> finalList = list.stream()
                .map(number -> Collections.nCopies(duplicateByNumber, number))
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```